# How to make column data in upper case by default in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, collation

Normally in SQL, select and insert statements use UPPER() and LOWER() functions to format the column cases. But in this application, whenever new data is inserted it must be stored as UPPER CASE by default.

**Example:**

insert --> INSERT 
Apollo --> APOLLO 
TyUiOP --> TYUIOP

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use a trigger to accomplish this but why not deal with this in the front-end of the application? Or, if you're displaying the data somewhere else (such as a report), set the case there?

Why do you want the data stored in a particular case?

Comment: Computed column?

Comment: No front end environment to handle this, the data is pushed from various resources like excel, notepad, database table copy. So the action must be on database side.

Comment: @Vignesh Rajendran - Check out [this answer](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=126208) from SQLTeam.com.

Comment: @SQL_Underworld I don't want to use trigger or any statements to achieve the solution, finding options by default a column change the data in UPPER case